Update Agent Status On Twilio mean available , busy , unable
I am integrating Twilio with my project. Outbound is happening. But Now I want that If agent update status then status also update on the twilio account . For This I am trying to find the rest api but unable to find.

If I understand, you want to update the activity of the worker, right?!
You can follow this documentation to do it
